# Check if the password is temporary on Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the `authData.getProviderData().get("isTemporaryPassword")`
method in Android API to check if the password is a temporary one. Though the method returns *literally* "**true**" while printing in log, if I use the method to redirect to a new Activity checking the if condition like

```
 if (authData.getProviderData().get("isTemporaryPassword")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PasswordReset.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        intent.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("password",password.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
```

it says ***"Incompatible Types Required: boolean Found:java.Lang.Object"***

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `#getProviderData()` returns a `Map<String, Object>`. That's why when you `#get()` the value, it's an `Object`. Since you know this is a boolean, you can cast it to `Boolean` to use in the `if` condition:

```
if ((Boolean)authData.getProviderData().get("isTemporaryPassword")) { …
```

You can't put an `Object` inside an `if` condition, only `boolean`. You can put a `Boolean` though because autoboxing will take care and convert to `boolean`.

That also explains why testing for `.equals(true)` works. When you do that, the method `.equals` will do the conversion to test if the value stored in this object returned is equivalent to `true`.

Comment: Great explanation Douglas!

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me

`if(authData.getProviderData().get("isTemporaryPassword").equals(true))`

Since `if()` itself checks for a true condition, I didn't understand why *equaling* it to **true** solved my issue. I dont think this is a proper solution, but it's working.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation for this behavior

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Douglas. I knew I was missing something.